# How to pass a IList<T> argument in a function

Tags: c#, function, collections

I have this function :

```
public static IList<T> myFunction<T>(IList<T> listaCompleta, int numeroPacchetti)
{
    return listaCompleta;
}
```

but if I try to call it with :

```
IList<SomeObject> listPacchetti = (from SomeObject myso in SomeObjects
                                  select myso).ToList();

listPacchetti = myFunction(listPacchetti, 1);
```

When I compile it says `The type arguments for method 'myFunction<T>(IList<T>, int)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

The fact is that I need to use a IList (or a collection indexes, not a IEnumerable) and I need to pass a generic object to the function (this time a `IList<SomeObject>`, next time maybe `IList<AnotherObject>`)

Can I do it? Or what about it? I think that I cannot use IList as type argument...

**EDIT** - Complete code

#### I CALL THE FUNCTION FROM ANOTHER CLASS

```
IList<Packet> listPacchetti = (from Packet pack in Packets
                                               select pack).ToList();

listPacchetti = Utility.Extracts<Packet>(listPacchetti, 6);
```

#### CLASS WITH FUNCTION

```
public class Utility
{   
    public Utility()
    {

    }

    public static IList<T> Extracts<T>(IList<T> listaCompleta, int numeroPacchetti)    // HERE THERE IS THE LINE WITH WARNINGS
    {
        return listaCompleta;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code looks fine to me.  What is the *exact* compiler error?

Comment: Added the whole error on the topic...

Comment: Hmm, there is no ambiguity there... `T` must be inferred to be `SomeObject`.  I suspect that the error is elsewhere.

Comment: @cdhowie : no I get the error only there. If I add <SomeObject> I resolve the trouble, but still some warnings on the function : `System.Collections.IList cannot be used as type generic`

Comment: hi, I can compile your code with no warnings or errors (.NET 4). What version of .NET are you compiling in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this;

```
    public class SomeObject
    { }

    public static List<T> MyFunction<T>(List<T> listaCompleta, int numeroPacchetti)
    {
        return listaCompleta;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var someObjects = new List<SomeObject>();

        var listPacchetti = (from SomeObject myso in someObjects
                                           select myso).ToList();

        listPacchetti =  MyFunction<SomeObject>(listPacchetti, 1);
    }
```

Comment: @markzzz - are you sure it's the same error? The error you've listed should be resolved by supplying the type arguments explicitly, as iain has done.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then your error isn't related to the code you posted!

Comment: Yeah it works, but there is a warning : System.Collections.IList cannot be used as type generic. Not so good code...

Comment: change to List<> I will change the xample

Comment: okay, I think the issue is that we are looking at different code :) Can you update the question with the actual code and indicate where the warning is? I can look at it better then.

Comment: VVS found the solution! ;) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Is your utility class compiled for .NET Framework 3.0 or higher and does your code have a reference to the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace?

So, is `using System.Collections.Generic;` missing?

Comment: YEs...that's was the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Markzzz: from what you've posted about the error regarding `IList`, I suspect you have the wrong namespace imported.  You need a `using System.Collections.Generic` at the top of your code, and I'm guessing you have `using System.Collections`.  That's why the compiler's telling you that `IList` can't be used as a generic.